# Plot pane shows just black screen

Tags: r, linux, graphics, rstudio, rstudio-server

Working on `RStudio Server 2023.06.1 Build 524`. Somehow I messed up the graphics device configs. E.g. `plot(1)` creates just a black new tab in the plot pane. Weirdly enough, the zoom window will show the plot. Other devices, e.g. `png(1);plot(1);dev.off()` also work fine.

[image]

I tried the usual stuff to no avail, e.g.

```
> graphics.off()
> dev.new()
NULL
> dev.list()
RStudioGD       png 
        2         3
```

I also closed the project, completely logged out of RStudio Server, manually `kill`ed all my `rstudio-server` processes - same. Found no relevant `*.Rdata` files and `rsession.conf` and `rserver.conf` have no entries.

I also cleared browser cache, tried a different browser - same.

**Any clues?!**

The error occurred after I accidentally ran a large script with many plots and impatiently hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> a few times to stop it.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: AlmaLinux 9.2 (Turquoise Kodkod)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: FlexiBLAS NETLIB;  LAPACK version 3.9.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=de_CH.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=de_CH.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=de_CH.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=de_CH.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=de_CH.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=de_CH.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=de_CH.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

time zone: Europe/Zurich
tzcode source: system (glibc)

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.3.1 tools_4.3.1  
>
> RStudio.Version()$l
[1] "2023.06.1+524"
```

Comment: Calling dev.off multiple times until you get error saying you have no device open usually works for me.

Comment: @zx8754 That's exactly what I mean by "the usual stuff", thx.

Comment: I suggest that the presence of *"impatiently hit `Esc` a few times to stop it"* means this is a hard-to-reproduce bug. Assuming that the rstudio-server instance works fine for you when you don't get impatient with it ("oops" moments like that happen to me often enough too), then perhaps this is well-suited as a bug-report or, better yet, a trouble-ticket (if you have commercial support). I can't find the GH repo, though, so perhaps the [Posit Community](https://community.rstudio.com) would get some response from somebody closer to rstudio-server devs?